# Efficient Pagination with Flask and Mongoengine

Tags: pagination, flask, mongoengine

I have a Flask app with which I would like to display paginated tables of data from a MongoDB Collection. However, there are potentially very many documents in this collection, so I would like to be loading them lazily - only loading the ones which are about to be displayed.

My problem is that on one page in my app, I would like to paginate:

`Stuff.objects()`

But on different pages I would like to paginate:

`Stuff.objects(__raw__=query)` or `Stuff.objects(message__in=Message.objects(__raw__=query))`

Calling any of those particular functions automatically loads all of the relevant objects into memory (as I discovered by running `locals()`) so I need to paginate the calls with:

`Stuff.objects().skip(number).limit(pagelength)`, or
`Stuff.objects(__raw__=query).skip(number).limit(pagelength)`

So it would seem that I need a Paginator class which I can simply pass `Report` into, then somehow specify the query information.

Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: have you seen this snippet ? http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [paginator](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/pagination.py) from [flask-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine)  You can use it like so:

```
paginator = Pagination(Post.objects, 1, 10)
print paginator.items
```

Comment: But will this achieve the same lazy/efficient effect if I do `Pagination(Post.objects(__raw__=query), 1, 10)`?

Comment: yes - the first part just has to be an iterable. Which an uncalled queryset will be then it slices based on the page and the count - which behind the scenes will add a skip and limit.  eg: `Post.objects(__raw__=query)[0:10]`  == `Post.objects(__raw__=query).limit(10)`

Comment: Did that work for you - if so please mark as answered and help other people in the future :)